# How to prevent MS Access report in subform scrolling down each time I use subform.Requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report in a subform called `ViewCurvePrices`. At the top of the parent form, a button contains the code:

```
ViewCurvePrices.Requery
```

It's pretty simple stuff and refreshes the values as I expect. Unfortunately though, the report also scrolls down about half a line after it runs, which seems like buggy behavior.

Have any of you come across this before, and is there a way to prevent this from happening? This doesn't happen when the requeried subform contains a regular form/datasheet - just when its a report.

I'm using MS-Access 2016.

Comment: This is caused by tab order control I think. Can you reset your tab order and see if that changes your issue

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Changing the order didn't work for me, but turning `Tab Stop` to `No ` in the field text boxes in the report did the trick. It does seem like an unfortunate byproduct of Tab Stop. If you put your comment in an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Suggested by OP:

I think maybe Tab order has something to do with it, however you have sense discovered that TAB STOP was the culprit.